# Procedure to insert Xml Into Sql Server -- Must Declare Scalar Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the below procedure to try and insert xml via the filepath into a xml column.  I am getting an error must declare scalar variable for ForeignId.   Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do, or am I on the right path?

Here is the procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[InsertXml] @path nvarchar(100)
                    ,@ForeignId uniqueidentifier
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000) = 
'INSERT INTO XmlTable(XmlId
           , ForeignId
           , TestXml)
SELECT NEWID()
     , @ForeignId
     ,* FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK ''' + @path + ''', 
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'
EXECUTE(@SQL);

RETURN @@ERROR;

END
```

Comment: There are already [dozens of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+must+declare+scalar+variable) about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're executing the SQL statement using `EXECUTE(SQL)` it has no access to the `@ForeignId` value

One way to solve this is to use [sp_excuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and do this instead of `EXECUTE(@SQL);`

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ForeignId uniqueidentifier';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @ForeignId ;
```

You could also just concatenate the @ForeignId to your sql string but I can't recall if there are issues with that when using a uniqueidentifier